# How do I do combinatoric algebra without tedious factorial multiplication and division?

Tags: combinatorics

I find combinatoric algebra very non-intuitive. I'm talking about Pascal's Identity $n\geq r$,
$$
\binom{n+1}{r}=\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}.
$$

I understand the tedious proof of the theorem but what's a trick for understanding combinatoric algebra in general? I can't eyeball and decompose a binomial without memorizing the formulas or doing tedious factorial multiplication and division.

It's never obvious how combinatoric algebra works:

EXample: [image]

Comment: The trick is to attend to what these numbers (here binomial coefficients and Stirling numbers) **count**.

Comment: You should probably describe what is the "tedious combinatoric proof" of that property of binomial numbers. I simply cannot imagine what "tedious factorial multiplication and division" you are doing...

Comment: Hi OP! In regards to your specific question about Pascal's identity, [Wikipedia gives a "combinatorial proof"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule#Combinatorial_proof). Searching for more examples of "combinatorial proof" should give you more examples of the kind of high-level arguments you're looking for. (On this site, there is an user Brian M. Scott who does [quite a lot of them - for example, here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236850/combinatorial-proofs-having-a-difficult-time-understanding-how-to-write-them-ou))

Comment: And on a related note, you might also appreciate the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321757/rigorous-nature-of-combinatorics). (Including mine!)

Answer (score 1):

For the second one:
You want to partition $\{1,2,\cdots ,n,n+1\}$ into $m+1$ non empty blocks(RHS). What if you first take out the elements that are in the block of $n+1$(Say there are $k$ elements) and then you partition the rest?(LHS)
I agree, "combinatorial algebra" is hard but that's why combinatorics uses two powerful concepts: Intuition on the combinatorial description (with interesting principles as sum, multiplication and bijection) and generating functions.

Comment: combinatorics have to do with cardinality and functions?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Define the numbers $n$ as cardinals of the set $[n]=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}.$ For example, $\binom{n}{k}=|\binom{[n]}{k}|,$ where $$\binom{[n]}{k}=\{A\subseteq [n]:|A|=k\}.$$ Which encodes the notion of choose $k$ from $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Your goal is to pick $r$ items form $n+1$ items.

suppose you pick the first item, how many more items do you still have to pick?

what if you did not pick the first item?